# How to catch error in nestjs when a query fails

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to `nestjs` and was trying to convert my backend from `nodejs` to `nestjs`. Hope that makes sense? I am using `typeorm. But I am not sure as what could be the best of way of catching errors.

`entity.ts`

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Course {

  @PrimaryColumn()
  course: string;

  @Column("varchar", { array: true })
  subject: string[];
}
```

`controller.ts`

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CourseService } from './course.service';
import { Course } from './course.entity';

@Controller('course')
export class CourseController {
    constructor(private courseService: CourseService) {}

    @Get()
    getCourses(): Promise<Course[]> {
        return this.courseService.findAll();
    }

    @Post()
    addCourse(@Body() courseDto: Course[]) {
        return this.courseService.create(courseDto);
    }
}
```

`service.ts`

```
import { Injectable, Catch, ExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost, ConflictException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, QueryFailedError } from 'typeorm';
import { Course } from './course.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CourseService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Course)
        private courseRepository: Repository<Course>,
    ) { }

    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        throw new Error("Error in course service." + exception.code);
    }

    findAll(): Promise<Course[]> {
        return this.courseRepository.find();
    }

    create(courseDto) {
        return this.courseRepository.insert(courseDto)
            .catch((err: any) => {
                // throw new ConflictException();

                switch (err.name) {
                    case 'QueryFailedError':
                        console.log("**++**" + JSON.stringify(err));
                        // throw new Error("Error" + err.message + "" + err.detail);
                        // throw new ConflictException();
                        throw JSON.stringify(err); //"Error creating a course" + err.message + "::: " + err.detail;
                    default:
                        throw err; 

                }
            });
    }
}
```

Now, all I am able to throw is `throw new ConflictException();`. I wanted to throw different errors based on the result, like -
1. For duplicate record
2. Missing mandatory fields
3. etc

But not sure how can we handle and customize the same and also make full use of nestjs.

Like I see the below trace in console but `500, Internal server in postman` -

```
{"message":"duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"PK_d7fc152bc721b3f55a56ed3ad33\"","name":"QueryFailedError","length":293,"severity":"ERROR","code":"23505","detail":"Key (course)=(II) already exists.","schema":"public","table":"course","constraint":"PK_d7fc152bc721b3f55a56ed3ad33","file":"d:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\access\\nbtree\\nbtinsert.c","line":"535","routine":"_bt_check_unique","query":"INSERT INTO \"course\"(\"course\", \"subject\") VALUES ($1, $2)","parameters":["II",["A","B","C"]]}
[Nest] 12152   - 04/10/2020, 1:18:40 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] {"message":"duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"PK_d7fc152bc721b3f55a56ed3ad33\"","name":"QueryFailedError","length":293,"severity":"ERROR","code":"23505","detail":"Key (course)=(II) already exists.","schema":"public","table":"course","constraint":"PK_d7fc152bc721b3f55a56ed3ad33","file":"d:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\access\\nbtree\\nbtinsert.c","line":"535","routine":"_bt_check_unique","query":"INSERT INTO \"course\"(\"course\", \"subject\") VALUES ($1, $2)","parameters":["II",["A","B","C"]]} +190924ms
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about passing the errors to your controller and let the controller throw those errors.

**service.ts**

```
create(courseDto) {
  return this.courseRepository.insert(courseDto)
}
```

and in your **controller.ts**

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';

...

@Post()
async addCourse(@Body() courseDto: Course[]) {
    return await this.courseService.create(courseDto).catch(err => {
      throw new HttpException({
        message: err.message
      }, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    })
}
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: What would be best, to let service handle it and controller handle it like you mentioned above?

Comment: From a design perspective I wouldn't support this solution. In hexagonal architecture an endpoint (ie. controller) is only **one** way to access your business layer. If you add a CLI command for your service or (staying in web context) a GraphQL resolver you would need to re-build all that error handling for each entry point. Better let the service layer handle the exceptions when they are crucial to the business. I.e. when the service require an entity to fetch/persist and it fails, let it fail.

Comment: @agoldev Totally agree with your statement, except if it's to return an HTTP-specific error (with a HTTP status code for example). Then in that case I would be OK with it (it would be incorrect to return it from the service), even though in Nest.js I'd prefer to see an exception filter so the code doesn't end up duplicated in every controller.

Answer (score 3):

Dont return service function directly, nest will catch that exception and assume its from controller, another solution is wrap with try/catch

controller.ts

```
try {
  return await this.courseService.create(courseDto)
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks your post helped me indirectly, my problem was I didn't have the `await`.